# Why is my java code here behaving this way where it returns true while it should return false? why if I remove the bool expression it still not work?

Tags: java

[image: problem description]

I included the image with the problem I have to solve;
I thought it should be easy. And expected my code to work. Yet it didn't...
I don't car a a lot about a solution as much as knowing what I did wrong

I know I need to start from right to left in reading the simple binary number (no encoding and not including negative values) as the power of 2 increases, but in this program it reads the binary number from left to right (like as a string)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter a 5-digit integer made of 0s and 1s:");
        String binaryNumber = myScanner.nextLine();
        
        int length = binaryNumber.length();
        int index = 0;
        int powerOfTwo = 1; // 2^0
        int decimalNumber = 0;
        int currentChar = 0;
        boolean isValid = true;
        while(index < length && isValid) {
            currentChar = binaryNumber.charAt(index);
            if(currentChar > 1 /*Therefore not a 0 or 1*/) {
                isValid = false;
                System.out.println("Error at index "+index+" which is "+binaryNumber.charAt(index));
            }
            decimalNumber += (binaryNumber.charAt(index) * powerOfTwo);
            powerOfTwo *= 2;
            index++;
        }
        if(isValid) {
            System.out.println(binaryNumber+" in decimal is "+decimalNumber);
        } else {
            System.out.println(binaryNumber+" is not valid ");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing where the script checks if a character is a (0 or 1) or not.

```java
if (currentChar \> 1 /\**Therefore not a 0 or 1\**/){....
```

Then it started calculating binary numbers like 0000 to be more than 0.

Comment: You're starting at index `0` and reading up to `< length`, so yeah, *"[...]  in this program it reads the binary number from left to right [...]"*.

Comment: I think I got an answer to my problem. The .charAt() returns a char not an integer. and that char which is 49 for representing 1 and 50 for 0 is being calculated as an int of value 50 or 49. 
Actually, when the variable is being dealt with like an integer, it's 49 or 50. When as string it is 1 or 0;

Comment: You don’t need to remember the Unicode numbers. Just use the right syntax: `if(currentChar != '0' && currentChar != '1') { /* invalid */ }` note that the character is not only invalid when it is bigger than `1`, it is also invalid when it is smaller than `0`, as there’s no guaranty that the user only entered digits. Of course, you also have to convert the character to a number, e.g. `currentChar - '0'`. But that’s only for educational purposes, use [`Character.digit(currentChar, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,int)) instead…